# User Data Model in DynamoDB

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

In C#, I'm currently using DynamoDB to try and structure my application/platform where I have 3 models on a single document:

1. Company
2. Department
3. Employee

In the example below, I have incorporated those models into a single item which I read is best practice to avoid relational database practices.

However, my question is how I would query my Employees when they log in or register themself? Username is always gonna be unique across the entire platform (no matter company or department)

- I need to find the specific Employee based on Username (to compare
  login details etc, when logging in)
- I need to know when a new Employee is registering, if an Employee
  with the same Username already exists or not.

  ```
  {
  "CompanyID": "035129ab-4d60-42b0-8bba-a2f0860ca93c",
  "CompanyName": "Test Company",
  "CompanyAddress": "Test Address 22",
  "Departments": [
      {
          "DepartmentID": "3549aaab-f244-48a5-8e9b-d871357cfb47",
          "DepartmentName": "Seattle Department",
          "Employees": [
              {
                  "EmployeeID": "61dcdf81-571f-4a70-9020-161719120da6",
                  "EmployeeUsername": "JohnDoe",
                  "EmplyeeEmail": "John@Doe.com",
                  "EmplyeeFullName": "John Doe",
                  "EmployeePassword": "C78AEB71D55B194A1CBE22533823663B"  
              },
              {
                  "EmployeeID": "b70e29da-eba7-425a-ab4a-6b96ed479c52",
                  "EmployeeUsername": "FooBar",
                  "EmplyeeEmail": "Foo@Bar.com",
                  "EmplyeeFullName": "Foo Bar",
                  "EmployeePassword": "FF0F0C99A83829F0D24A1B1BDC2E7780"  
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
  ```

  }

Is this the best way to do it? Is there a better way? I would very much appreciate any help! :)

Thanks!

Comment: This might open up a can of worms when it comes to when to use and not to use a relational database. You are dealing with relational data in this example so it does make sense to store it the way you have demonstrated but it would make even more sense to store it in a relational database :P Even in Amazon's own examples they demonstrate this type of relational data stored in separate DynamoDB tables.

Comment: @ShawnLehner I see.. The thing is tho that I need something that's fast, reliable and automatically scales. A normal MSSQL Database doesn't do that. Is this not achievable/good practice in DynamoDB?

Comment: I would store them in separate tables with references between the document IDs. The only downside to this is if you need to do a relational query, you may have to make multiple queries instead. However, this can be mitigated by making sure you have the appropriate ID references available in each table.

Comment: To expand on your comment about "fast, reliable and automatically scales". I agree, this is a big benefit to DynamoDB. Provisioning your read/write access is a struggle of its own though, mainly because if you don't have unlimited budgets, you are going to provision low and increase as needed. Unfortunately, if you ever hit your limit you get nasty error responses instead of just slow access which in some cases can be an even worse situation for software developers.

Comment: Hmm.. That makes sense.. I'm not too worried about budgeting as that part is relatively OK.. What are your thoughts on doing it reverse? Having the Employees and under the Employees are the Company and Departments. This would obviously create alot of duplicate data, but could easily be updated to the other users through Non-unique keys on the Employees.. Would this be a better approach?

Comment: I think that could work but you are really just doing it so you can query a bit easier. Like you said, it is going to create a lot of duplicate data. It is also going to be a pain to update company/department information if it changes down the road because you will have to traverse every Employee record looking for departments and companies ... Is there a reason you don't want to store them in separate DynamoDB tables?

Comment: No there is no reason why I wouldn't store all these 3 models in 3 different DynamoDB tables, but as you mentioned earlier, the downside of that is that I might have to make multiple queries. Maybe that's still worth it tho. I think I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I agree with the concept that storing relational data in NoSQL, a single document approach like this makes sense on the surface. However, when you start digging into it a bit more, you run into quite a few issues.

The first, and the biggest for me, is how easy the data is to query. In your example, you have employee lists spread across multiple documents, nested fairly deeply into the documents. This can make it very difficult (and slow) to query on this information. Many NoSQL solutions provide indexing on child keys, but even this can be complex to configure correctly.

You could obviously adjust the hierarchy of your nesting, and move the Employee data to the root level as you mentioned in your comments. This would make it much easier to query on Employees. However, now you are duplicating data. The duplication is not a major issue because of the extra data, it is mainly a concern of data congruence. What if you need to update the information for a department or company? Do you have to loop through every employee document and update their department as well? Are you splitting IDs between these departments so you know which ones are the same? How do you merge data once you get it out of the database?

For this example, it is absolutely relational data. The best place to store it would be in a relational database. If you are concerned about availability, scalability, etc ... Why not use Amazon RDS and use Amazon Aurora? Sure, the cost is going to be a bit higher to get started than DynamoDB but this is going to be a great long term solution for relational data.

If you are set on using DynamoDB, I would store the data in separate tables. It is going to be the cleanest in the long run. This will mean you need to query multiple tables in some cases, but you should be able to mitigate this using [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) which according to the documentation:

> returns the attributes of one or more items from one or more tables

I hope this insight helps. If you have any questions, please feel free to comment and I will do my best to answer!

Comment: Hi Shawn, thank you so much for taking the time to respond :) What you are saying makes alot of sense. I just looked at Aurora and I have a few questions. 1) Does Aurora have the same kind of auto scalability like DynamoDB? I simply want to be able to create a DB&Tables and that's that. No need to think about upgrading and downgrading.. 2) How well does it work with a .NET Environment (ASP.NET Core) ?

Comment: I honestly have had very little experience with Aurora besides sitting through a few of their workshops during Re:Invent. From my understanding, you should be able to setup RDS to auto-scale but don't quote me on that. As for it working with .NET, I am pretty sure you can just use the .NET Core MySQL drivers because it is designed as a MySQL replacement.

Comment: I see.. I did some research, and while Aurora is obviously better built for it, I think DynamoDB will scale and be better cost effective in the end (as it's only running whenever theres a request).. Hmm..